# DAO per entity or per use case

Tags: java, design-patterns, dao

I have a situation where I am thinking should I be creating a DAO per entity or per use case.

I have a table "user" which stores login information of users.

```
create table user (user_id varchar(50) not null primary key, password varchar(50))
```

I have a table "user_login_history" which stores history of how many times a user login in the system.

```
create table user_login_history (user_login_history_id int not null identity(1,1) primary key, user_id varchar(50) not null foreign key references user(user_id), login_date datetime not null)
```

*This is the use case:* For a user to login into the system, he/she should pass these 2 checks:

1. User Id and Password should match in the user table
2. 30 days has not passed after the last time user login into the system.

So I have an entity **User**

```
public class User {
    private String userId;
    private String password;
    public String getUserId() { return this.userId; }
    public void setUserId(String userId) { this.userId = userId; }
    public String getPassword() { return this.password; }
    public void setPassword(String password) { this.password = password; }
}
```

And I have an entity **UserLoginHistory**

```
public class UserLoginHistory {
    private int userLoginHistoryId;
    private User user;
    private java.util.Date loginDate;
    public int getUserLoginHistoryId() { return this.userLoginHistoryId; }
    public void setUserLoginHistoryId(int userLoginHistoryId) { this.userLoginHistoryId = userLoginHistoryId; }
    public User getUser() { return this.user; }
    public void setUser(User user) { this.user = user; }
    public java.util.Date getLoginDate() { return this.loginDate; }
    public void setLoginDate(java.util.Date loginDate) { this.loginDate = loginDate; }
}
```

So I think I have 2 choices:

1) create DAO by entity which means 2 DAOs: 
    **UserDAO** for **User** entity which will be based on "user" table and 
    **UserLoginHistoryDAO** for **UserLoginHistory** entity which will be based on "user_login_history" table

```
public interface UserDAO {
    public User getUser(String userId, String password);
}

public interface UserLoginHistoryDAO {
    public UserLoginHistory getLastUserLoginHistory(String userId);
}
```

2) create DAO by use case which means 1 DAO: 
 
    **LoginDAO** which will have all the sql needed for the this use case.

```
public interface LoginDAO {
    public User getUser(String userId, String password);
    public UserLoginHistory getLastUserLoginHistory(String userId);
}
```

which choice is preferable and why?

If I go with choice 1, what if I need query which uses both "user" and "user_login_history" tables and returns columns from both tables; in that case in which DAO these types of queries will go? UserDAO or UserLoginHistoryDAO or a new DAO for composite?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that there is a third option whereby you keep both DAOs (with the one-to-one mapping between the accessor and db table) but then overlay a third accessor which facilitates an easier operation of the lower level APIs. This third accessor requires the other two accessors for construction, so;

```
public LoginAccess(final UserDAO userAccess, 
                   final UserLoginHistoryDAO userHistoryAccess)
```

The benefits of this approach are that;

1. You can keep the scope of your accessors as low as possible - do the user/user history DAO implementations require `public` accessors if the expected use is only via the `LoginAccess`?
2. You can create more *unit-like* test cases for this set-up. All db level tests are more on the side of integration tests regardless but a set of tests per table-based query are good to have and a set of tests per function (without worrying about the SQL being used) are also good to have. Conversely, a set of tests which check a function and SQL in one step are inherently more brittle.
3. This third approach follows more closely the SOLID principles

I think 1 & 2 are key - generally I find that if there is a way I can write more effective unit tests and reduce the public-facing API then I will adopt that approach. If later my approach is proved inadequate (likely!) I have a robust testing suite upon which I can aggressively refactor.

Comment: there will be a User Maintenance Screen where a user can be added, deleted or modified. I will need UserDAO there.
also there will be a Screen to list user login history. I will need UserLoginHistoryDAO there.

Answer (score 1):

I think the right approach is to use DAO per entity/table and then have another upper layer (service/business etc) that would use these DAOs for implementing the required functionality. This approach is more scalable and will keep your code clean.

In this case, you can have LoginService where you would call UserDAO and UserLoginHistortDAO to implement required functionality.

I think only exception to above approach is performance where we give priority to performance over other non-functional requirements. In this case, we may have to design our DAOs based on Use Case rather on the entity/table.

Answer (score 0):

Always create DAO as a mirror image to database, means one per database object. That will reduce complexity in your application layer now and in future

Comment: I understand. Its a clean approach.

Comment: Always? How about more than one per database object so that you can make use of the CQRS pattern?

Comment: Right it makes it even more simpler, not complicated. I was opposing the idea of writing use case driven DAO-s. I don't know if Query Model in CQRS advocate one model per use case...